# Couldn't install remote agents for TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2018.
Now I am trying to install a remote agent (from another machine).
I am getting this error:

[image]

I've checked this and I have found this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2019

I think this issue is related to the fact that the machine is not trusting the certificated TFS Generated during the installation.
I also checked the log file:

```
[2019-02-18 13:48:33Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://jbpatfssr005/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

(...)

```
[2019-02-18 13:48:33Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
```

In my browser when I try to access TFS I get a message sayng that the site is insecure.
[image]

So I guess this is really because of the certificate.
But how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you need to specify the full URL:

```
https://jbpatfssr005:8080/tfs
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error info and screenshot.

Seems you are trying to install agent with version 2.1221

Just as the doc stated:

> This error may indicate the server certificate you used on your TFS
>   server is not trusted by the build machine. Make sure you install your
>   self-signed ssl server certificate into the OS certificate store.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2019

If somehow you can't successfully install certificate into your machine's certificate store due to various reasons.

The agent version **2.125.0 or above** has the ability to ignore SSL server certificate validation error.

You could try to install a build agent with higher version. The source of build agent, you could download [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases).

Answer (score 0):

My TFS is running on the following URL: https://jbpatfssr005. When I was installing it I tried to use jbpatfssr005/tfs but I got errors so I left it whithout the tfs.
I read the documentation and I tried the following command in powershell:

```
PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri jbpatfssr005 -UseDefaultCredentials.
```

I got this result:

[image]

So I guess TFS installed the certificate correctly right?
I'll try to install a newer agent.
@PatrickLu-MSFT I'll report back the results.

Comment: any update on your issue, were you able to install the agent?